# How to present another view controller by tapping on a label inside a tableview cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I want to create a segue to from an object (label) inside a tableview cell to another view controller.

example: imagine the instagram feed tableview - tapping the number of likes under an image will push a second view with the list of people who liked an image.

How can i do that? 
I know it's possible when tapping a cell but i need a solution for when tapping a label inside the cell...

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the following steps :

1. Define `userInteractionEnabled = true` for the label using Interface Builder or in code, as you wish, (VERY IMPORTANT!!) without this the tap is not enabled.
2. Define an action to the **Tap Gesture Recognizer** to handle the tap inside the `label`.
3. To present the another `ViewController` you can do one of the following two things :

   - Make a modal segue from the `Tap Gesture Recognizer` to the another `ViewController` using the Interface Builder or make an action for the **Tap Gesture Recognizer** and then present the another `ViewController` manually using the `presentViewController` function.

I thought the first is more easy to present the another `ViewController`, Is up to you.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing - if each cell in the tableview holds data from an object, and the cells get polulated from an array of objects called "cellsArray" how can I find the index in the array that points to the object in the cell with the label I tapped on? Is there a way to get the cell's indexPath when tapping on. An object in the cell?

Comment: Yes , you can set a 'tag' in each label with the index of the cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` , but you have to define a custom UITableViewCell for the cell and define an outlet inside of the class to you can make then `cell.label.tag = indexPath.row` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and then in the `tapLabel` action you can retrieve the index of the cell

Comment: Somehow I cannot get it to work and what i have seen is similar to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683564/segue-from-uitableviewcell-by-tapping-on-an-image-inside-of-cell The solution from this post was a bit complicated. Do you mind paste your code and maybe this author and me are both missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a button and set its title instead of using a label. If you have to use a `UILabel` for some reason, then you can do so by setting its `userInteractionEnabled` property to `true` and then adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it.

Comment: Is there a difference between labels and buttons in terms of appearance? I seem to think so, but I need to take a close look when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var lblTxt: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handleTap:"))
        recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        lblTxt.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        lblTxt.userInteractionEnabled = true;
}

func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        println("tapped!")
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondView") as SecondViewController
        self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
```